# How to run a cmd line application in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, telnet

I want to run this command

```
telnet -a servername port
-CASServer V2.00 connection from 0.0.0.0 [] Diag mode only
status
Clients: Static 0/50  Dynamic 19/50
Application1: 1 0xcb4388 hSock(0x2d4)
Application2: 0 0
OK
```

I am basically only interested in "Dynamic 19/50". If possible, I'd like to get this information from PowerShell

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: I don't even know where to get started

Comment: I found a Cmd-Telnet script but it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell script at http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1887-get-telnet-telnet-to-a-device-and-issue-commands might work for what your're trying to accomplish. It creates a PowerShell function called 'Get-Telnet'; it can establish a telnet connection and send a series of commands.

Your usage would be something like:

```
Get-Telnet -RemoteHost [servername] -Port [port] -OutputhPath results.txt
```

After which you could parse the data you need (e.g., the 'Clients' line) from 'results.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a cmd line application in PowerShell, specifically the telnet command, you first need to install telnet.

Use this command, with admin privs:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

After installing you can run your `telnet -a servername port` command in PowerShell:

[Running a command line application (telnet) in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnUre.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive on what exact command line application you are trying to run.  However here is an example of running a command line application in powershell.

```
&'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.14\bin\gswin64c.exe' -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -r600 "-sOutputFile=$OutputFullDirectory" "$InputPath"
```

This would be ghostscript however the key is using the & symbol to call the command line and then enter in the path to the exe file you want to run then you can pump in the parameters.  Hope this helps lead you in the right direction

Comment: Its TELNET part of Windows

Comment: Windows has a Telnet client, but it's usually not installed by default: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/telnet-faq#1TC=windows-7